# What would be the best way to test if a file has one of several acceptable file extensions?

Tags: bash, if-statement, file-extension

I have the following code to test if the file held in $arg is not one of several file extensions.  In an effort to learn I want to know if there is a more correct, more compact way to do this.

```
if ! [[ -f "$arg" && ( $arg = *.mkv || $arg = *.mp4 || $arg = *.mp3 || $arg = *.flac || $arg = *.avi) ]] ; then
    echo -e "\"$arg\" is an invalid directory, filename or file format\n"
fi
```

Comment: With `extglob`, you can do: `if ! [[ -f $arg && $arg = *.@(mkv|mp4|mp3) ]]; then ...`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe wrap it up in a function?

```
has_element() {
  local item="$1"
  shift
  local e
  for e; do
    [[ "$e" == "$item" ]] && return 0
  done
  return 1
}

suffix="${arg##*.}"

if has_element "$suffix" mkv mp4 mp3 flac abcdefg hijklmn; then
  echo "$suffix is in one of the extensions"
else
  echo "$suffix is not in one of the extensions"
fi
```

Comment: Did you forget to `local e="$1"`.  Thanks for the suggestion.  It is more versatile and compact.

Comment: @deanresin I did `local item="$1"` and `e` is only meant as a loop variable.

Comment: I'm so confused.  `e` is never assigned anything so why would the loop execute even once?  and shouldn't there be an `if` before the `[[`?  I'm new to bash so maybe there is some shorthand I'm not understanding.

Comment: Consider `[[ $item = *."$e" ]]` so that you don't need to extract the extension.